# Calling non-static method from a threading server

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a bit difficult to explain and I have had to reduce the code down to what I think are the important parts as it's just too big to post it all.

I have a multi-threading socket server that serves some data to clients, everything works fine until it receives 2 or more simultaneous requests and what appears to happen is that the data returned from the requests is not correct and actually contains one of the other request's data.

So I figure that this is probably caused by my main client() method being defined as static and therefore the variables used in it are updated by each request and are global instead of being only for each individual request.

My main method must be declared as static, and I believe that the server should also be static since there is only 1 instance, however the thread requests cannot also be static otherwise it results in the variable corruption I am facing now.

The problem is I cannot compile it as the client() method throws an error 'non-static cannot be called from static context'.

So how can I call a non-static method from my server thread who's variables have their own scope that are not static and over-written with each request.

As I said at the start, it's a bit difficult to explain, I hope I have covered it ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  try {
    new Server().start();
  }
}


public void client(Socket socket, int conidx){
    ... code    
}


private static class Server {

    private void start() {
        ..code  
    } 

    .... code

    try {
      Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
      executorService.submit(new ServiceRequest(s));
    }

    class ServiceRequest implements Runnable {
        ... code

        public void run() {
          client(socket,conidx);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to create the instance of the main object first (let call it Main as you didn't include that piece of code).

Secondly, the Server inner class must not be static so it lives within the context of enclosing class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.exit(run());
}
...
public int run() throws Exception {
   try {
      new Server().start();
   }
}
...
private class /*no static here*/ Server
{
    class ServiceRequest implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            client(socket, conidx);
            // or Main.client(socket, conidx);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but despite changing this and having no static method or variables declared, sending multiple requests at the same time results in the data from the last request being used in all requests.